# Photo gallery like picasa or facebook

Tags: javascript, photo-gallery

I create a photo gallery like picasa or facebook have and already have done a server part. Now faced with an issue about displaying it. In other words, there's a page contains some small pictures (in fact, thumbnails). I'd like a "windows" contains a big picture to appear by clicking a picture instead of redirecting to other page.

For example. like [here](https://plus.google.com/photos/101639182097262188840/albums/5740893306708579601?banner=pwa&gpsrc=pwrd1&authkey=CMij6fPincKoFg)

So please recommend me something or give me an example of how to make it.

Answer (score -1):

There are a lot of image galleries online. [Here](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox) is example of one. Click on each of the rounded buttons (1-5) to see demos.

Comment: Good, but just not what I want. I want the gallery that is exacly (or almost exactly) shows pictures like picasa does.

Comment: I understand this is a question about showing a group of images together sized in a way that puts images next to each other without empty spaces. Thus this answer is not relevant.